# No Result using Object in Scala

Tags: scala, databricks

I am trying to print the value of 1, 2 or 3
using this code

but it just says

defined object Demo

```
import scala.collection.immutable._

object Demo {
  val mymap : Map[String, String] =
  Map("1" -> "ME", "2" -> "SUPERMAN", "3" -> "ZOD")
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
  
    println(mymap("1"));
    
  }
    
  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the tags you used (`databricks`), it looks like you are using either a REPL or some other online worksheet. As such, you don't have to create an object with a `main` method, but just write in your code, as follows:

```
import scala.collection.immutable._

val mymap: Map[String, String] =
  Map("1" -> "ME", "2" -> "SUPERMAN", "3" -> "ZOD")

println(mymap("1"))
```

You can play around with this code with another Scala online worksheet, called Scastie ([here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/CTYm876pQxWBhkCEzJRbLg)).

Alternatively, you can also call `Demo.main` directly from outside of the object definition, passing `Array.empty` as its only argument.

A few of further notes:

- I'm not 100% whether this is true for your environment, but in general importing `scala.collection.immutable._` is not strictly necessary
- in Scala you can make use of type inference and skip the `Map[String, String]` type annotation: the compiler will infer it for you
- semi-colons are optional in Scala